# How to use different/multiple @param

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have a method in a helper class to do some repetitive tasks. I have to pass to it different classes.

Something like

```
@param Entity $entity || Entity2 $entity etc..
```

I tried it like this but it sees only first of classes. Others, above in use statment section are unused?

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe in the docblock like this:

```
/**
 * @param Entity|Entity2 $entity
 */
```